# jOOQ: Code generation with maven

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jooq

Good day,

I am trying out a simple postgreSQL setup with java using jOOQ. Now I created a table called Products using pgadmin3, with two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Products"
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  username text,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public."Products"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Now, I'm trying to use java to interact with this table. I can request a list of tables from postgres, so I know the connection works. However, if I try to do a maven install (with generate as the goal, I want my java classes) I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/PublicFactory.java:[15,58] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PostgresFactory
  location: package org.jooq.util.postgres
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/tables/Products.java:[12,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class UpdatableTableImpl
  location: package org.jooq.impl
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/Keys.java:[31,120] method createUniqueKey in class org.jooq.impl.AbstractKeys cannot be applied to given types;
  required: org.jooq.Table<R>,org.jooq.TableField<R,?>[]
  found: org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.Products,org.jooq.TableField<org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.records.ProductsRecord,java.lang.Integer>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.Products cannot be converted to org.jooq.Table<R>)
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/tables/records/ProductsRecord.java:[52,66] incompatible types: org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.Products cannot be converted to org.jooq.Table<org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.records.ProductsRecord>
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/PublicFactory.java:[83,62] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getSettings()
  location: class org.jooq.util.maven.example.PublicFactory
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/tables/Products.java:[24,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/tables/Products.java:[34,125] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<java.lang.Integer>,org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.Products)
  location: class org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.Products
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/tables/Products.java:[39,130] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method createField(java.lang.String,org.jooq.DataType<java.lang.String>,org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.Products)
  location: class org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.Products
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/tables/Products.java:[49,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/tables/Products.java:[54,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/tables/Products.java:[60,9] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/dries/workspace/postgres/target/generated-sources/jooq/org/jooq/util/maven/example/Public.java:[36,40] method asList in class java.util.Arrays cannot be applied to given types;
  required: T[]
  found: org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.Products
  reason: varargs mismatch; org.jooq.util.maven.example.tables.Products cannot be converted to org.jooq.Table<?>
```

The class does get generated, it seems (as I can find it in the target folder). However in eclipse or intellij I cannot find it in the path. 
Either way, the build process should not fail.

Does anyone know why the build fails?

Thanks and good day.

Comment: "`PublicFactory`" - what ancient version of jOOQ are you using? :) Mind upgrading first? Also, can you please post your relevant `pom.xml` configuration?

Comment: Good lord, I was on 3.7.2 for jOOQ BUT i seem to have accidentally copy pasted the plugin from 2.6.4. The google results sometimes lead to outdated versions of the docs. I will blame monday for this one! Thanks Lukas :)

Comment: Better look forward to Tuesday, then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in order to have a formal answer here on Stack Overflow, here's my comment again as an answer.

From the way it looks, you're using an outdated jOOQ code generator version with a newer jOOQ runtime version. The two won't match, which is why you're getting those exceptions.

I've noticed because that `PublicFactory` class is no longer generated by the jOOQ 3.x code generators.

Comment: It would be nice if you put the latest code generator sample... when looking to the doc, I found plenty of older config and not able to find the correct setting (especially when using spring-boot)

Comment: @рüффп: Can you please point to the outdated doc?

Comment: forget it, it is just IDEA showing the plugin in red but the generation worked properly. It seems because Idea does not sees the ${jooq.version} in the `spring-boot-starter-jooq`. My issue was just an import discarded and re-creating it resolved my issue.

Comment: In case someone is using Spring Boot, I fixed this by removing the <version> element  for the jooq-codegen-maven plugin in the pom.xml file.

Comment: @AlejandroDuarte: It may or may not be related to this question, but you could ask *and* answer your own question if you're interested. [This is explicitly encouraged by Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions)